# iOS - GCM message not received when kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption flag is set to false

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform

I've created an iOS app that receives GCM notifications. All was created just like in tutorials and for tests I had separate project created in Google console. I'm moving app to production and I've tried to switch to a newly created google project - I've created APN certificates and used them in google console and got it working. The problem is that Application receives GCM messages only when **kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption** flag is set to true. I've tried everything including recreating configs but it's all the same. For some reason the same messages are handled correctly on Android devices.

Answer (score 2):

It may have something to do with the APNS certificates set, if you check out the [Setting up a GCM Client for iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client), it indicates that as you said,`kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption` should be `YES` for development and `NO` for production. It also has a note

> Make sure that the value of kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption matches your certificate type. All requests will fail if you use a development certificate to connect to the production environment, or a production certificate to connect to the sandbox environment.

Comment: I've recreated certificates again and it behaves the same. I upload p12 certs to gcm for both environments and have them in the keychain on my mac. I'm missing the connection - how iOS app knows which cert to use (if uses at all) during compilation phase to know which gcm environment work with?

Comment: I've also uploaded just production certificate to gcm for both modes and IT works the same - just with sandbox = true